# How to do a left double quote that looks right both as monospaced and non-monospaced fonts?

Tags: fonts, typewriter, quotation

As best I can tell, if I want a correct left double quote mark:

- in all non-monospaced fonts I must do ``X
- in all monospaced fonts I must do "X

In my case this is an issue because I have a macro that needs to take some text as an argument that it may need to typeset using one, the other or even both kind of fonts.

**Is there any combination of quote convention and monospaced/normal fonts that get left double quote correct both ways?**

### A Minimal Example That Demos The Problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}

\newcommand{\Foo}[1]{ % format the same argument in different fonts.

% monospaced look like garbage
\medbreak\begin{empty}\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont#1\end{empty}   Courier

% Okay, unless you really look
\medbreak\begin{empty}\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont#1\end{empty}   Palatino 

% Easy to see issues.
\medbreak\begin{empty}\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont#1\end{empty}   TeX Gyre Adventor

}

\begin{document}
\Foo{``X'' ``X" "X" \enquote{X}}  % try different way to quote things.
\end{document}
```

### What I've already tried

Most of the searching I've done just gets results talking about how to get correct left double quotes for non-monospaced fonts. I've found a small number of results about left double quote in monospaced fonts, but nothing that deal with both.

I found a hint that it might be possible to get something by installing a custom monospaced font, but I need as self contained a solution as practicable. (That `pdflatex` is breaking hermeticity already annoys me, but I can live with that.)

Comment: Side question: Is LaTeX set up with the assumption that monospaced fonts are `code` fonts? That would explain not combining single ticks. (In my case the text to by typeset as monospaced is *not* code.)

Comment: Did you try with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: Can you promote that to an answer? It seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OT1 encoded monospaced fonts don't have the “double back quote” ligature, because in the `cmtt` fonts the place of the double open quote is used for a different glyph (the backslash).

Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`; all T1 encoded fonts should have that ligature (and also the undirected double quote if you type `"`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}

\newcommand{\Foo}[1]{ % format the same argument in different fonts.

% monospaced look like garbage
\medbreak{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont#1}   Courier

\medbreak{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1}  CMTT

% Okay, unless you really look
\medbreak{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont#1}   Palatino

% Easy to see issues.
\medbreak{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont#1}   TeX Gyre Adventor

}

\begin{document}

\Foo{``X'' ``X" "X" \enquote{X}}  % try different way to quote things.

\end{document}
```

[image]